# How to effecivelly aggregate tex data - python

Tags: python

i have following data in text file:

```
tag=bmw: One
tag=audi: Two
tag=bmw: Three and Four
tag=saab: Five
tag=audi: Six
tag=bmw,audi: Seven
```

And i would like to achive sth like:

```
bmw:
    One
    Three and Four
    Seven
audi:
    Two
    Six
    Seven
saab:
    Five
```

I use python script and i can eassily read input file and parse the text. 
Then i came to a moment when i have a TAG and its DESCription after reading each line.

And I have a question: how can i store it, so i could use it later (after whole text file is read) and effectivelly aggregate them by TAGs.
I dont know what TAGs will appear and how many of them there will be.

Comment: your ending format is yaml

Comment: Please do not care about format. I would like rather to know how to store it? Should i use lists somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate them into a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with the entries as `lists`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list) # values will all be lists

with open('yourfile.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        k, v = line.split('=')[1].split(':')
        for key in k.split(','):
            d[key.strip()].append(v.strip())

d
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'bmw': ['One', 'Three and Four', 'Seven'], 'audi': ['Two', 'Six', 'Seven'], 'saab': ['Five']})
```

And now you can do lookups against your brands like `d.get('bmw')`

Comment: from collections import defaultdict <- thats what i needed - thanks!